# When #temp table in SQL SERVER will be dropped?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table "#tblResourceC7" like this:

```html
Id          Class                Code                 Value
----------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
1           F1                   A                    100
2           F1                   B                    100
3           F2                   C                    220
4           F3                   A                    150
5           F2                   C                    300
6           F3                   D                    120
```

Then I create a new table "#tblResource9" by run this query,

```html
SELECT *
INTO #tblResource9
FROM
(
    SELECT Class, [A], [B], [C], [D] FROM
    (SELECT Class, Code, SUM(Value) AS SUM_VALUE 
        FROM #tblResourceC7 GROUP BY Class, Code) AS TBL7
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(SUM_VALUE)
        FOR Code IN ([A], [B], [C], [D])
    ) AS PIVOTTABLE
)
AS KQ9
```

I have a result when "SELECT * FROM #tblResource9":

```html
Class                A           B           C           D
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
F1                   100         100         NULL        NULL
F2                   NULL        NULL        520         NULL
F3                   150         NULL        NULL        120
```

BUT, when I bring these code to a query string like this:

```html
DECLARE @QUERY91 nvarchar(MAX);

SET @QUERY91 = 'SELECT *
                INTO #tblResource9
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT Class, [A], [B], [C], [D] FROM
                    (SELECT Class, Code, SUM(Value) AS SUM_VALUE 
                       FROM #tblResourceC7 GROUP BY Class, Code) AS TBL7
                    PIVOT
                    (
                        MAX(SUM_VALUE)
                        FOR Code IN ([A], [B], [C], [D])
                    ) AS PIVOTTABLE
                )
                AS KQ9
                ';

EXEC (@QUERY91)
```

Everything work fine (3 row(s) affected).
But why I don't have table "#tblResource9" when I "SELECT * FROM #tblResource9" (Invalid object name '#tblResource9').

Comment: #tblResource9 is temporary table and will be available only for that particular session and it will not be available outside of it.. means, this table only accessible within that store procedure or function or within that statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary tables will be dropped when your session ends, except if it was created inside a stored procedure, then it will be dropped when you exit the procedure.

[Create table in books online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
> automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be
> referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored
> procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by
> the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.
>
> All other local temporary tables are dropped automatically at the end
> of the current session.
>
> Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session
> that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped
> referencing them. The association between a task and a table is
> maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This
> means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of
> the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the
> table when the creating session ended.